# How to add a suffix to the end of a string in a line?

Tags: replace

Here's an example of content in a file

```
This_is_line_1    :  1
This_is_another_line  :2
This_is_3rd_line    :3
Here_is_line_4 :4
```

So, how can using emacs to add  char `@` immediately to the end 1 string on each line, i.e.

```
This_is_line_1@   :  1
This_is_another_line@  :2
This_is_3rd_line@    :3
Here_is_line_4@ :4
```

Comment: Don't forget to make @Tobias' answer as "The Answer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the beginning of the buffer an call [`query-replace-regexp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Query-Replace.html). You can call `query-replace-regexp` by the menu item "Edit → Replace → Replace Regexp". Alternatively you can use the key-sequence <kbd>M-C-%</kbd> that is shown beside the menu item.

Use `^[^[:space:]]+` as [regular expression (regexp)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html#Regexps) and `\&@` as replacement string.

Notes:

1. The first caret in the regexp matches the empty string at the beginnig of the line. It anchors the match at the beginning of the line.
2. The outer braces `[...]` describe a character set. Each of the contained characters match.
3. The caret in the character set negates the set. I.e., all characters not in the set do match.
4. The `[:space:]` is the character class of characters with space syntax.
5. The `+` matches one or more instances of the previous expression, i.e., of the character set.
6. The regexp is greedy by default. That means as many as possible chars are matched.
7. The `\&` in the replacement string [references the full match](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html#Regexp-Replace).

Comment: Very informative. The docs are a little hard to follow. As a side note, the wonderful utility re-builder allows you to experiment!

Comment: @Tobias, thank you for your solution.

Comment: I have a further question about the solution. If I want to put the 1st string between two '@' chars, what change do I need in step 7 of the provided solution. For instance,      @This_is_another_line@

Comment: You get `@This_is_another_line@` with `@\&@`.

Comment: @Tobias, thank you for your following up solution.  It works wonders. By the way, how/where can I  find  out the meaning of "\&"?

Comment: @vbrnrt I have added [a link](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html#Regexp-Replace) to the section Regexp Replace in the Emacs manual.

Comment: @Tobias, thank you for the link. It's very helpful